# Prove If hcf(a,b)|c then then ax+by=c has an integer solution. Where a and b are non-zero integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I'm not sure whether to use multiple cases for this particular question (i.e. odd*odd with hcf=1 and odd*even with hcf=1 have integer solutions for x and y).

Answer (score 1):

By [Bezout's Identity,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for some $\,m,n\!:\,\  a m + b n = \gcd(a,b).\,$  Multiply through by $\ldots$ so RHS $ = c$